# need help my else statement won't print

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this very basic piece of code. When I run it the else statement doesn't work. The three if statements get the proper webpages and print the statements just fine.

```
import webbrowser
import time

breaks = 3
breaks_taken = 0

if(breaks_taken == 0):
    breaks_taken = breaks_taken + 1
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R03cqGg40GU')
    print('this program was started at ' + time.ctime())
if(breaks_taken == 1):
    breaks_taken = breaks_taken + 1
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfuCLp8VEng')
    print('this program was started at ' + time.ctime())
if(breaks_taken == 2):
    breaks_taken = breaks_taken + 1
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MsvER1dpjM')
    print('this program was started at ' +time.ctime())
else:
    print('this is your final break')
```

Comment: `else` only executes if the preceding `if` (in this case, `if(breaks_taken == 2):`) evaluates as false, which it doesn't, based on the way you increment `breaks_taken`. If your intent is to print `'this is your final break'` at the end of the `if` statements regardless, then remove `else` and un-indent your last line.

Comment: that worked, thank you.